# Why does @Inject of a @Singleton in Java always result in null when using Guice?

Tags: java, singleton, guice, inject

I'm trying to implement the simplest possible Java program where a `@Singleton` object is injected via `@Inject`. However, after `@Inject`, the object is always `null`.

I realized that I need to use Guice to bind a certain behavior. I'm doing so through `MyGuiceModule`, which `extends AbstractModule`. However `MyGuiceModule` never got called so I had to add this line:

`Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyGuiceModule());`

But it does not work. Here are my files:

**LonelyObject**

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class LonelyObject {
    public LonelyObject() {
        System.out.println("LonelyObject Constructor");
    }

    public void alive() {
        System.out.println("I AM ALIVE");
    }
}
```

**TheTest**

```
public class TheTest {
    // inject LonelyObject here
    @Inject
    LonelyObject L;

    public TheTest() {
    }

    // use LonelyObject
    public void doit() {
        L.alive();
    }
}
```

**MyGuiceModule**

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Singleton;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class MyGuiceModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        System.out.println("MyGuiceModule extends AbstractModule");

        // make sure LonelyObject is always instantiated as a singleton
        bind(LonelyObject.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}
```

**main function**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("main");

    // this is only here so MyGuiceModule gets called, otherwise
    // it will be ignored. this seems to be the only way I can see
    // to configure Guice. note that the returned Injector is not used.
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyGuiceModule());

    TheTest t = new TheTest();

    // crashes here with Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    t.doit();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## You're bypassing Guice entirely.

Actually, the culprit is this line:

```
TheTest t = new TheTest();
```

You shouldn't create your instance yourself. Instead, ask Guice to create it for you:

```
TheTest t = injector.getInstance(TheTest.class);
```

An alternative would be to request Guice to inject the fields directly in your instance for you (but this recommended only when integrating legacy libraries):

```
TheTest t = new TheTest();
injector.injectMembers(t);
```

Comment: Got it. However, that means I still have to have some sort of "global" initialization function where I can actually instantiate TheTest this way. I thought the whole point of Guice was so that you do not need a "global init" function where you initialize things.

Comment: You call it only once. I'm not sure what your beliefs are, but there is no need to call any other instance ever after if the first instance is your main app instance and you used Guide everywhere.